# ViewModel function has some invalid arguments

Tags: c#, compiler-errors

I have a program to get some data from json, put it in a listview and I can press refresh button to get new data. When i press the button first time I get the data, but if I press it again, I get this "The best overloaded method match for 'MyApp.ViewModels.TableViewModel.UpdateWithModel(MyApp.Model.TableModel)' has some invalid arguments"

**TableModel.cs (model)**

```
 public class TableModel
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public Data data { get; set; }
        public string Unit { get; set; }

    }
    public class Data
    {
        public double x { get; set; }
        public double y { get; set; }
        public double z { get; set; }
    }
```

**TableViewModel.cs (ViewModel)**

```
using Model;
    public class TableViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private string _name;
        public string Name
        {
            get
            {
                return _name;
            }
            set
            {
                if (_name != value)
                {
                    _name = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("Name");
                }
            }
        }

        private double _x;
        public string X
        {
            get
            {
                return _x.ToString("0.0####", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            }
            set
            {
                if (Double.TryParse(value, NumberStyles.Any, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out double tmp) && _x!= tmp)
                {
                    _x= tmp;
                    OnPropertyChanged("x");
                }
            }
        }

        private double _y;
        public string Y
        {
            get
            {
                return _y.ToString("0.0####", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            }
            set
            {
                if (Double.TryParse(value, NumberStyles.Any, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out double tmp) && _y!= tmp)
                {
                    _y= tmp;
                    OnPropertyChanged("Y");
                }
            }
        }

        private double _z;
        public string Z
        {

            get
            {
                return _z.ToString("0.0####", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            }
            set
            {
                if (Double.TryParse(value, NumberStyles.Any, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out double tmp) && _z!= tmp)
                {
                    _z= tmp;
                    OnPropertyChanged("Z");
                }
            }
        }

        private string _unit;
        public string Unit
        {
            get
            {
                return _unit;
            }
            set
            {
                if (_unit != value)
                {
                    _unit = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("Unit");
                }
            }
        }


        public TableViewModel(TableModel model)
        {
            UpdateWithModel(model);
        }

        public void UpdateWithModel(TableModel model)
        {
            _name = model.Name;
            OnPropertyChanged("Name");
            _unit = model.Unit;
            OnPropertyChanged("Unit");
            _x= model.data.x;
            OnPropertyChanged("x");
            _y= model.data.y;
            OnPropertyChanged("y");
            _z= model.data.z;
            OnPropertyChanged("z");
        }

        #region PropertyChanged

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        /**
         * @brief Simple function to trigger event handler
         * @params propertyName Name of ViewModel property as string
         */
        protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

        #endregion

    }
```

**MainViewModel.cs (ViewModel)**

```
public ObservableCollection<TableViewModel> NewMeasurements { get; set; }

public ButtonCommand RefreshFnc { get; set; }

private tableServer iotTable = new tableServer();


void RefreshData()
        {
            // Read data from server in JSON array format
            dynamic measurementsJsonArray = iotTable.getMeasurements();

            // Convert generic JSON array container to list of specific type
            dynamic measurementsListA = measurementsJsonArray.ToObject<List<TableModel>>();

            // Add new elements to collection
            if (NewMeasurements.Count < measurementsListA.Count)
            {
                foreach (var m in measurementsListA)
                    NewMeasurements.Add(new TableViewModelOri(m));
            }
            // Update existing elements in collection
            else
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < NewMeasurements.Count; i++)
                {
                    NewMeasurements[i].UpdateWithModel(measurementsListA);
                }
            }
        }
```

**EDIT**

in this line `NewMeasurements[i].UpdateWithModel(measurementsListA);` I have just replaced measurementsListA to measurementslistA[i], and it worked.

Thank you for your answers, I will certainly look out for dynamic type.

Comment: The danger of using `dynamic`. If you define `measurementsListA` as `List<TableModel>` instead of `dynamic` it wouldn't even compile.

Comment: Doing measurementslistA[i] will not do the trick when measurementsListA has less elements than NewMeasurements. 
If some of the replies provide an answer to your question you should accept those answers in order for this question to be marked as answered.

Answer (score 1):

It look like your method is waiting for a TableModel

```
public void UpdateWithModel(TableModel model)
```

But you try to give it a List

```
dynamic measurementsListA = measurementsJsonArray.ToObject<List<TableModel>>();
NewMeasurements[i].UpdateWithModel(measurementsListA);
```

**Edit**

As the.Doc say in the comment it's dangerous to use "dynamic" type if it's not necessary. With static type you would have get a compiler issue instead of a runtime issue.

Answer (score 0):

In the following code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < NewMeasurements.Count; i++)
{
    NewMeasurements[i].UpdateWithModel(measurementsListA);
}
```

...you are passing `measurementsListA` which is a list, while `UpdateModel` expect a `TableModel` object.

During the first refresh the error does not pop up as NewMeasurements is empty.